# passing an html form array to php file

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, http-post

I am trying to get information from an html form and pass it to my php file as an array

here is a snippet of the code for my html form:

```
<form action ="upload.php" method="post">
    Name<input id= "n" type="text" name="info[name]" /><br />
    Address: <input id="a" type = "text" name="info[address]" /><br />
    City: <input id="c" type = "text" name="info[city]" /><br />
</form>
```

then in my php file I tried to print the content:

```
$information = $_POST['info'];

echo $information['name'];
```

but nothing gets printed to the page

Comment: i want to store the array in the $information variable and then print it using $information

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` would show you what exactly got posted to give you a better idea on how to handle it, it's a good way to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that (shove it all into a separate array (apart from `$_POST`)) directly with your HTML. You'll have to do some extra PHP work at the beginning.

Firstly, for the love of all that is holy, make your HTML input names cleaner:

```
<form action ="upload.php" method="post">
Name<input id= "n" type="text" name="info_name" /><br />
Address: <input id="a" type = "text" name="info_address" /><br />
City: <input id="c" type = "text" name="info_city" /><br />
</form>
```

And now, for the PHP:

```
//this is how I would do it, simply because I don't like a bunch of if/elseifs everywhere..
//define all the keys (html input names) into a single array:
$infoKeys[0]='name';
$infoKeys[1]='address';
$infoKeys[2]='city';
//define your end array
$information=array();
//now loop through them all and if they're set, assign them to an array. Simple:
foreach ( $infoKeys as $val ){

if(isset($_POST['info_'.$val])){

$information[$val]=$_POST['info_'.$val];

}//end of isset

else{

$information[$val]=null;

}//end of no set (isset===false)

}//end of foreach

//now, when you want to add more input names, just add them to $inputKeys. 
//If you used the if/elseif ways, your doc would be plastered in ifs and elseifs. 
//So i personally think the looping through the array thing is neater and better. 
//but, feel free to change it, as I have a feeling I'll have allot of critics because of this method.

// anyway, that should do it. The var $information should be an array of all your 'info_' html inputs....
```

Happy coding!

Comment: You don't need to specify the array keys. PHP will do that automatically.

Comment: Also, it would probably be better to use a ternary operator when setting `$information[$val]` so it can have a default value of `null`.

Comment: @BaylorRae' There may be other data in `$_POST`, which the OP may not want in the array. Which is why I used the array, to specify exactly which ones the OP wants and which ones she/he doesn't. But your other comment, about the default, I have made edits. But, I didn't bother with the ternary operator as the OP is probably a newbie, and I know when I was a newbie, I certainly didn't like the looks of those things.

Comment: I meant in the `$infoKeys` array, you could simplify it to this. https://gist.github.com/6b2da0ad53a9266520ef